# Are "Network Planning" and "Networks Planning" different?

Tags: differences

Does the 's' in 'Networks' imply a different meaning, or are the two interchangeable?
Thanks!

Comment: The primary difference is no one would say "networks planning" (if you heard this, it was likely a possessive/genitive, i.e. "the network's planning").

Comment: Thanks! Glad I wasn't the only one to whom it sounded weird. Actually, it's just the result of literally translating from Hebrew, where we use the plural form in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, especially technical English, there are many nouns that are used as adjectives (adjectivised). As a compound term where network functions as an adjective, it's: network planning.

That said, in an article or longer description, one might want to say: (the) planning of networks was not part of the original contract. But even there, it would mean "network planning".